# creating a "login with" provider pseudocode if account already exist

Tags: authentication, firebase-authentication, login-control

I am trying to figure out how to address the issue of what to do when the email already exists in certain situations. I am currently using firebase, but I believe it would be the same problem no matter what software you use. Is there a standard way to do this?

**Example:**

1. Login with Email / Register
2. if "email" exists then error( EMAIL_EXISTS )
3. else create account & login
4. user must verify email

   EMAIL_EXISTS = "Please login with your <%provider%> account, your email already exists"

---

1. Login with Provider (google, fb, twitter, etc) / Register
2. If "email" exists then add provider to account providers
3. else create account (possibly ask for new password) & login

---

1. Login with Email
2. Click Connections / Providers
3. Add Google / Facebook / Twitter etc to account

Is there a standard way to do this? I feel like I am missing some steps. I keep seeing many apps that do not address the issue and you must have a different account for each provider which is different than your email account. Obviously a good programmer thinks about these things.

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

The first 4 steps are pretty much how you should implement it with Firebase Authentication if you have the <kbd>One account per email address</kbd> setting enabled (which it *is* by default) in your [Firebase Authentication console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/authentication/providers).

But if you want this flow in your app, I highly recommend checking if there is a FirebaseUI library with Auth for your platform. It exists for [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/firebaseui), [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/firebaseui), and [Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/firebaseui), and implements many common auth flows in a consistent way.